# How to SELECT data 30 last data from ID

Tags: mysql, sql

Now my ID is AUTO_INCREMENT and recive data 1 time per day.
But I have to select the last 30 rows of data to display.

In the sql.
"SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` BETWEEN (SELECT MAX(`id`)-30) AND (SELECT MAX(`id`))"

but it showing all the data.
What did i do wrong please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select last 30 data rows you can use following query.

```
select * from tbl_name order by id desc limit 30;
```

Comment: But if use "dest" the data will showing row 30,29,28,.....,1. i want to show data row 1,2,3,...,30. How to ?

Comment: To show 1,2,3... use order by id asc limit 30.